# Is there an easy way to start a static function of a class in a few clicks in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there an easy way to start a static function (not main) of a class in a few clicks in Eclipse?

Can do it in main function, but is there another way?

E.g. right click on a needed function in the Outline view and select [run with arguments..]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify please.

Comment: @Shervin We have a static function of a class. One way to test how it works is to make a call to it in the "main() function". How to avoid this "long" way of starting a static not-main functions ?

Comment: weird request... since it will only applicable when the parameters are all primitive (or string). How will you define the parameters are objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A static method cannot be run, except of course if this method is the `main(String... args)` method.

However, consider creating a **JUnit** test case for this method instead.

Create a `JUnit Test Case` within Eclipse. In the wizard, you can indicate the class that provides your `static` method in the `Class under test:` field. Then Eclipse will give you the ability to create one test method per existing method on the class under test.

Once your JUnit test is created, simply right-click on this Java class and select `Run as > JUnit test`. The shortcut is Alt+Shift+X, then T.

You can also consider doing some [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)...

Answer (score 1):

Create a JUnit Test class for your static methods. Once created, it's only one click to test your static methods.